# Using jsoup with mailinator

Tags: android, google-chrome, jsoup, pop3

I am attempting to extract some HTML from a mailinator email in my android app. I would like jsoup to find a link to the email with a given subject. Using the chrome "inspect element" feature I see the subject like this: `<div class="span5 subject ng-binding">
                                Free Popcorn at Landmark Cinemas
                            </div>`. However, jsoup sees it like this: `<div class="span 5 subject">{{email.subject}} </div>` How can I get jsoup to see the actual email's subject? Should I abandon using jsoup for this and do something with POP3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution: Use yopmail instead of mailinator.